# Regex shorthand quotation mark to \enquote{}

Tags: editors, sharelatex

I recently switched from Google Docs to LaTeX and I've written half of my Thesis in Goolge Docs. The problem is that I c&p-ed the Text to my LaTeX editor and now the double quotation marks (") are doing weird stuff.

Can you help me with a regex function to transform this pattern `"word"` into `\enquote{word}`, so I can exchange this quickly?

```
\"\($*\)\" => \\enquote{\$\}
```

This somehow doesn't work.

Or is it even possible that there's a config for doing that and I can keep writing the standard quotation marks (")?

PS: I'm using the [sharelatex.com](http://sharelatex.com) editor

Comment: I wouldn't use l3regex for this I'd use your editor, typically the syntax would be something like `"\([^"]*)"` --> `\\enquote{\1}`  although systems differ some need `\(` rather than `(` and some use `$1` rather than `\1` to reference the group.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [David](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) I got the solution:

```
([^"]*)" ->  \enquote{\$1}
```